# REST client, do I need a local server (probably not), do I need Dynamic Web Project?

Tags: java, json, rest, maven

I need to a **JSON REST-Client** to send json via html

- DELETE
- PUT
- GET
- POST

method, and get json response, to be able to set headers as well.

I want to use the minimum of dependencies and 3rd party jars.

From my search in the web I found a code samples using local web server like tomcat, and dynamic web projects.

I want to use a simple java/maven project, with the minimum 3rd party jar and  without any server (I don't get why should I need one, I just need to connect to remote server and server of my on).

Thanks

btw. the samples use spring or jersey, it's best to use just `HttpConnection` of Apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind working against your existing server for development, then you certainly don't need your own.

Java provides an easy enough to use HttpUrlConnection class that can you can readily leverage to make HTTP requests to your server.

But I would suggest any of the multitude of JSON libraries ([json.org](http://www.json.org), [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), [gson](https://github.com/google/gson), etc.) to help manage marshaling the JSON. It's simply easier to pick one of those up than rewrite that wheel.

Other than that, you don't need any 3rd party jars for a project like this. You certainly don't need Jersey or Spring.